# Send data to a placeholder in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to display data from a list. Data in the list is updating inside a function. Actually I want to display the data only after execution of that function.

**Here is my template code.**

```
    <div class="modal-body">
          <td>{{shopName}}</td>
    </div>
```

**And this is my script.**

```
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "ViewShop",
      props:{
            shops:Object
        },
      data(){
        return{
          shopName:[],
        }
      },
      methods:{
        async shopd(sid){
          this.shopName=this.shops;
          console.log(this.shopName) // This prints the data in the console

        }
      }

    };
    </script>
```

I want to print the value of shopName in my template after executing the function `shopd()`

I think the `shopName` is accessed in template **before executing the function.** So what I need is **it should wait until the function make some changes** in `shopName` and then it should accessed to the template.

Answer (score 0):

For that you will need an auxiliary variable:

```js
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "ViewShop",
      props:{
            shops:Object
        },
      data(){
        return{
          shopName:[],
          showShopName: false,
        }
      },
      methods:{
        async shopd(sid){
          this.shopName = this.shops;
          this.showShopName = true;
        }
      }

    };
    </script>
```

Then on your template:

```html
    <div class="modal-body">
          <td>{{ showShopName ? shopName : "" }}</td>
    </div>
```

Comment: Still it's not working. I think the shopName is accessed from the template before executing function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use v-if directive. The html inside v-if will not be part of the dom until the v-if condition is met.

```
<div class="modal-body" v-if="shopName.length>0">
      <td>{{shopName}}</td>
</div>
```

Not sure if shopName is array or string the condition may change accordingly. And you can learn about conditional rendering from the documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I do not know if you need an array as the type or just a simple string. But in the template you can do this. If you change the type of the variable shopName to null and use the v-if directive to hide the element.

```
   <div class="modal-body" >
      <td v-if=shopName !== null>{{shopName}}</td>
   </div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html